# Astro and React RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

Can anyone help me with this issue? When I execute npm run build and npm start locally, everything works fine. However, when I upload it to a server (I'm using Railway), it doesn't work, and the following message appears.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Web browser Message

[image]

Could anyone offer a solution and explain to me the reason for this issue? I have tried thousands of solutions, but none have worked, here is the code and configuration.

Comment: What build/server settings do you use locally? E.g. static or output: server with an adapter. You could also try using the `client:only="react"` directive when deployed to Railway (it will skip any server pre-rendering for this component if that's ok for your use case).

Comment: I used all directives, I think the problem lies in Railway Platform and how the container is built for dependencies, because I tried it in Vercel and it worked fine. I spent a lot of time trying to use it in Railway but eventually gave up. Maybe in future I will try again or anyone discover the problem. I will posted here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue as well and found it was caused by Railway's way of auto detecting how to build the app. When I used Docker to build the app instead the issue went away. Used this guide here: https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/docker/#_top